# MVVM Error Message Handling in Subclasses: Seeking Input

Tags: c#, mvvm, eventhandler

I'm looking for input on a MVVM design-decision. I want to send error messages from my subclasses to my MainWindowViewModel. Is this a good way to go about it or are there simpler or better ways to handle this?

MainWindowViewModel Class:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    server = new Server();
    server.ErrorMessageChanged += ErrorMessageChanged;
}

private Server server;
private string tbError;
public string TbError
{
    get { return tbError; }
    set { tbError = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
private void ErrorMessageChanged(object sender, string msg)
{
    TbError = msg;
}
```

Server Class:

```
public event EventHandler<string> ErrorMessageChanged;

private string errorMessage;
public string ErrorMessage
{
    get { return errorMessage; }
    set
    {
        errorMessage = value;
        ErrorMessageChanged?.Invoke(this, errorMessage);
    }
}

public void SomeFunction()
{
    try 
    {
        //...
    }
    catch
    {
        ErrorMessage = "some error";
    }
}
```